# UITableView: highlight the last cell but other cells get highlighted as well

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have UITableView that I use as a sliding menu as part of SWRevealViewController.

I want to select the last cell in UITableView and implement the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IGAWindAloftMenuTableViewCell

    ...


    let sectionsAmount = tableView.numberOfSections
    let rowsAmount = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)

    if (indexPath.section == sectionsAmount - 1 && indexPath.row == rowsAmount - 1)
    {
        customCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    return customCell
}
```

When I scroll all the way down, it works -- the last cell is highlighted. However, when I scroll up and down, other cells in the middle of the table get highlighted as well.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to undo the change made in the `if`-branch for all other cells:

```
if (indexPath.section == sectionsAmount - 1 && indexPath.row == rowsAmount - 1) {
    customCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
} else {
    customCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or whatever color
}
```

The reason for the undesired side effect is the reusing of cells. A cell gets created, then it gets used as the last cell, then it moves off-screen and is reused somewhere else. It still contains the changed color information but is no longer at the corresponding position.