# Last cell is highlighted when selecting first cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have an odd problem with my UICollectionView. When I select the first cell in my Collection View the last cell is highlighted but does not show up in the array of selected index paths. Why is this happening?

Here is the code I am using to select and deselect the cells?

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = highlightedCellBorderWidth
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        selectedImages.append(imageArray[indexPath.item])
        print(selectedImages)
        print(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0
      let index = selectedImages.index(of: imageArray[indexPath.item])
        selectedImages.remove(at: index!)
        print(selectedImages)
          print(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems)
    }
```

Comment: Collection view cells are reused.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239523/uitableview-highlight-the-last-cell-but-other-cells-get-highlighted-as-well) on S.O. which was helpful. To solve the problem I simply added the following code to my  `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}`.

Code...

```
 if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(indexPath) == true {
        print("This cell is selected \(indexPath.item)")
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    }else{
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0

    }
```

Comment: There isn't a need to check if a cell is selected when it is being prepared by the collection view. If you're using a custom cell, `prepareForReuse()` is a better location for resetting the border. Otherwise, just initialize to zero when you dequeue a reusable cell and let the selection logic work later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how your cell is initialized, but...

`collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAt:)` is only called when the user successfully deselects an item. It does not get called if you deselect an item programmatically. If you are not resetting your layer's `borderWidth` when initializing a cell, the non-zero width will carry forward when the cell is reused by the collection view.